# List nodes under nodePool

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to re-deploy jenkins pod on kubernetes.

After I tried it, I am getting error and the pod is not initializing.

After I describe the pod, I can see

```
  Warning  FailedScheduling   46s               default-scheduler   0/12 nodes are available: 12 node(s) didn't match node selector.
  Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp  7s (x4 over 38s)  cluster-autoscaler  pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added): 2 node(s) didn't match node selector
```

Also, I see that there is a defined nodePool, which is `Node-Selectors:    nodePool=default`

I have a kubernetes deployment called `jenkins` where I can see that this value is defined.

I am not sure what should be the nodePool, since I am not sure how can I list all nodePools that I have available.

I can list all nodes using `kubectl get nodes`, but I do not see any info about nodePool there.

Any advice how to do this?

Comment: Show the output of ```kubectl get nodes --show-labels```

Comment: This should be the answer, thanks! Please post it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check the lables using `kubectl get nodes --show-labels` looks like your deployment has wrong labels